# Gitlab, find a commit using the revision ID?

Tags: gitlab

How do you find the committed files in Gitlab, when you have the hashed revision ID? It doesn't seem to be working in the "search" field.

I have seen people raise requests for this in 2017 and 2018.

Please tell me this exists??

Answer (score 3):

if you know the project you can always connect to the "commit" using the url:

`https://gitlab.com/{{user-o-group}}/{{repo-slug}}/-/commit/{{revision-id}}`

exemple : https://gitlab.com/michel47/bin/-/commit/b0d58fae

and if you want a specific file you can use its name with the "blob" url :

`https://gitlab.com/{{user-o-group}}/{{repo-slug}}/-/blob/{{revision-id}}/{{filename}}`

example : https://gitlab.com/michel47/bin/-/blob/b0d5/gitid

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the main 'commits' page in the gitlab ui for your repo (navigate by going to the sidebar, code -> commits), and simply search for the commit id using the browser's search function (like Ctrl+f or command+f). It lists all the commits without paging, so it actually just works, in my experience.

And yes, this has been a request in Gitlab forums for many years now.